# Difficulty using Orderby in Foreach loop C#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to order my files by their substring at the end of their names which happens to end with a number that indicates their position relative to the rest of the files. (example: fs-1632_1.txt --> fs-1632_2.txt).

I am currently able to get the numbers and turn them into ints I just have problems getting the OrderBy Method to work correctly. I am mostly working off of  [this example of Orderby](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
internal class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Number { get; set; }
}

private void OrderByEx1(List<FileInfo> files)
{
    int num = 0;
    int index_num = 0;
    string file_num  = "";
    string file_name = "";

    foreach (FileInfo in files)
    { 
        file_name = file.FullName;
        file_name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file_name);

        index_num = file_name.LastIndexOf("_") + 1;
        file_num  = file_name.Substring(index_num);

        num = Int32.Parse(file_num);

        Data[] set = {new Data {Name = file_name, Number = num }};

    }
    IEnumerable<Data> query = set.OrderBy(data => data.Number);

    foreach (Data file_s in query)
        MessageBox.Show($"{file_s.Name} {file_s.Number}");
}
```

Comment: `I just have problems` - What problems? Be more specific. The result is empty? Wrong order? Wrong results?

Comment: should `Number = num` not be `Number = file_num`

Comment: It doen't work at all I don't know how to use it, the code can't even run as currently displayed. everything past num = Int32.Parse(file_num); doesnt work

Comment: @Jaxi Probably not, because `file_num` is alphanumeric and `num` is numeric. Using `file_num` would do an alpanumeric sort, which sorts 2 after 11.

Comment: The `set` variable is only in scope inside the first `foreach` loop and you're trying to use it later. It also gets completely overwritten on every iteration where I suspect you really wanted a collection of them.

Comment: Also, set is being accessed outside of the scope, so surely that won't work either?

Comment: yes I want a collection of them

Comment: you have to initialise `Data[] set` outside the foreach loop and add it from inside the foreach loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the `foreach`-loop. You could use this safe LINQ approach:

```
files = files
    .Select(f => new { File = f, Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name) })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.File,
        x.Name,
        Token = x.Name.Substring(x.Name.LastIndexOf("_", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1)
    })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.File,
        x.Name,
        x.Token,
        IsInt = int.TryParse(x.Token, out int number),
        ParsedNumber = number
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.IsInt)
    .ThenBy(x => x.ParsedNumber)
    .Select(x => x.File)
    .ToList();
```

If there is no number or it can't be parsed to `int` the file will be listed at the bottom.

Comment: for me, this is basically unreadable, I just started coding in general let alone C#. I will try and understand whats going on here but I like Steves answer

Comment: @Reachingout I know what you mean, LINQ kind of looks like a whole new language at first, and that's probably because of how it was inspired by SQL. Nevertheless, it's powerful and very useful so it's worth looking into.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is there any reason you used three selects instead of one?

Comment: @Reachingout I definitely understand what you mean, I have been programming for around a decade and only recently started using Linq because of how weird it seemed. Once you understand it it is very powerful and very easy to read though. It helps a little to think of each step as an instruction that doesnt actually do anything until you iterate it (e.g. ToList in the code above). In this code they are utilizing anonymous objects which are like Tuples with names. So they gather all required data then sort it and take the `File`. With the added benefit of  zero intermediate variables.

Comment: @marie: just readability and because i wanted to avoid to do things multiple times like `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` or `Substring`. Therefore i store the results in variables in anonymous types.

Comment: I actually just took this and put it in my program because it keeps the FileInfo object (which I need to use later in the program) the same, and @Marie response helped me understand what I was looking at.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a Data array named set, add a single element to it and then restart the loop forgetting what you have loaded in the previous loop. The order is executed only when you exit the loop, but at that point the set array contains a single element, the last one.

You need to add your Data structure to a list and then order that list

```
    List<Data> dataFiles = new List<Data>();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    { 
        file_name = file.FullName;
        file_name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file_name);

        index_num = file_name.LastIndexOf("_") + 1;
        file_num = file_name.Substring(index_num);

        num = Int32.Parse(file_num);

        dataFiles.Add(new Data {Name = file_name, Number = num });
    }
    // If you don't need the query var you can just order directly in the for loop
    // IEnumerable<Data> query = dataFiles.OrderBy(data => data.Number);

    foreach (Data file_s in dataFiles.OrderBy(data => data.Number))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(file_s.Name + " " + file_s.Number);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Steve this answered my question. I had a feeling I had to do something like what you just posted; I just had problems instantiating the List correctly. thanks a lot!

Comment: Look also at the answer from Tim Schmelter. Albeit a bit difficult to understand it shows you the great power of linq.